# Why the contribution of Iranic languages is being ignored?

Tags: indo-european, arabic, persian, indo-aryan

As an Iranian something bothers me: I noticed more similarity between Iranic language families and Indian (Sanskrit) language and between with European language families compared to Indian languages and European language families. Why the term is Indo-European languages, not Indo-Iranian-European language families?
Another question I have is why it is always being said Arabic language influenced Persian in terms of scripts and wording, while there are many evidences showing the script was being used before Persia conquered by Muslims. The script was from Arami language and was one the formal scripts during Sassanid empire. The script being used by Muslims at that time was an older version evidenced by the very first versions of Quran written by the fourth caliphate. In this version the letters have no dots, which makes it challenging to understand, for example the written form of the word Tasein (90) and word Sabein (70) are the same due to lack of the dots.
Or the word Kafer in old Persian means to cover, and the word “Kaf” in today Persian means foam.

Another example is the name “Fatima” which is an old Iranian name, mentioned by Herodotus (I am copying from Wikipedia): Phaedymia (or Phaedyme, Phædima; Greek: Φαιδύμη) was the daughter of Otanes, a Persian noble mentioned in the Histories of Herodotus.[1] She was married in turn to Cambyses II, Gaumata (False Smerdis) and Darius I.[2]
The name in old Persian means soft face (pa(r) + dim).

I can bring lots of examples, which makes me more sad. However, I don’t want to articulate my questions with examples, as I am asking these questions to share my bad feelings and ask your opinion as some times I think maybe I am biased because the culture and language after Islamization of Persia was kinda a minority.

Answer (score 4):

It’s called Indo-European because when it was first discovered that Indic and Iranian languages were related to European ones, the name coined for the newly-discovered family was based on its geographical expanse – it basically means ‘spanning from [the western border of] Europe in the west all the way to [the eastern border of] India in the east’. The two parts are geographic, rather than linguistic, even though both are quite vague (‘Europe’ in particular is huge and home to half a dozen different Indo-European branches). This naming scheme is not uncommon – compare Afro-Asiatic languages (of which Semitic is a branch), which are/were spoken in a belt across northern Africa and into western Asia.

In German, they instead went for *Indogermanisch* (‘Indo-Germanic’) for Indo-European, which is a little more specific since it’s based on *linguistic branches* rather than vague geographic entities: Germanic is the westernmost branch of Indo-European (Icelandic being the westernmost Indo-European language – we’re not counting the Americas here), and Indic was the easternmost.

I say “was”, because since these names were coined, we’ve discovered some more languages to add to the family, including Tocharian, which is even further east than Indic. Even so, the family hasn’t been renamed ‘Tochario-European’ or anything like that – for better or worse, we’re stuck with ‘Indo-European’.

Also note that ‘Indo-Iranian-European’ wouldn’t make much sense as a name either. For one thing, Iranian is a single (sub)branch of Indo-European, which ‘European’ is not, so we’d be mixing apples and oranges. Even if we just said it’s geographical, adding Iranian in the middle would then lead to the obvious question why all the *other* countries that speak Indo-European languages are left out, and we’d end up with an *extremely* long name.